# In the Split-Bregman algorithm, what's the interpretation of the constraint strength parameter?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, sparsity

So, I've got the standard $L_1$ minimization problem: $\arg\min_x \{\|Ax-b\|_2^2+\lambda|Wx|_1\}$. I use Split-Bregman to solve this problem and it becomes $\arg\min_{x,d}\{\|Ax-b\|_2^2+\beta\|Wx-d\|^2+\lambda|d|\}$. It's convenient because now we're solving separately a quadratic problem in $x$ and another much simpler one with the $L_1$ norm in $d$.

So, in my original problem $\lambda$ is the strength of the regularization term of the problem. It's always difficult to justify setting a free parameter but somehow we'll manage. In the second problem instead I've got two free parameters!! The regularization strength and a parameter that enforces the equality $d=Wx$. How am I supposed to set $\beta$? Does it have any physical interpretation? As it is just enforcing a constraint it would look like any value would lead to the same results, doesn't it? But obviously this is not the case. What am I missing?

Comment: I would choose another method. Fore example, dual proximal gradient. In that case you do not have to guess any algorithm parameters.

Comment: There are proximal methods developed by Nesterov for exactly such problems (so-called max-type regularized problems, a huge class of problems which includes things like total-variation regularization, etc.) luthuli.cs.uiuc.edu/~daf/courses/optimization/MRFpapers/…. See equations 2.1 and 2.2 and note that $\|Wx\|_1 = \max_{\|u\|_\infty \le 1}u^TWx$

Comment: Also see Algorithm 2 of this paper arxiv.org/pdf/1605.09658.pdf (disclaimer: I'm coautor)

Comment: I'll look into those. However, can I ask you why you'd reccomend Nesterov over Split-Bregman. Mind you, I'm a noob in convex optimization, but I found SB to be extremely simple and to solve my (toy for now) problems extremely well.